# Django: dynamic template rendering

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm working on a site that has some mostly static content that I still want to use Django template tags in. I don't want to have to write a view and add a urlconf entry for each URL, I just want to add templates to a specific folder and have them be rendered and accessible on the web. Is there already a project out there that does this?

Comment: I don't know projects that you seeking, but in Django you can only use `TemplateView` in urls to render your templates. It will look something like this `r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='main/index.html')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a catch all view and resolve template dynamically:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import django.template
import django.http

def view_template(request, template_name):
    try:
        return render_to_response(template_name)
    except django.template.TemplateDoesNotExist:
        raise django.http.Http404('No such file: %s' % template_name)
```

And in your url-conf add, towards the end:

```py
url(r'^/(?P<template_name>[\w-]+\.html)$', view_template),
```